# how make chart size flexible on any number of entries

Tags: css

im new in web design,i[image: theChart] have a kendo chart,when the number category axes is 12 or less,its fine and readable, problem starts when number of category axis increase to 20 or more,in this case what could be the solution?below is the css and also the screenshot of what happens when the number of entries increase,

Here is the CSS:

```
<div style="width:1200px;margin-top:20px">
     <div id="faultstatSubCat" style="width:40%;float:left;margin-left:35px;">
     </div>
    <div id="faultStatTurbineName" style="width:60%;float:right">
     </div>
   </div>
```

The chart is the one with 60% of width and floated right ,left one is another chart,i attached the careen shot also

Comment: Invert your chart, that labels go from top to bottom and bars goes from left to right, then you have plenty of space downward.

Comment: @Justinas if want to keep it like this the solution is horizontal scroll?

Comment: @mpris1983 Yes. Or some kind of different chart type. Like zoomable ones.

Comment: @Justinas I want to make it scrollable (horizontally)without any affect on the chart next to it,can you tell me how can I make it scrollable ?

Comment: Well, you have to decide how big your chart must be. Then simply apply to wrapper `overflow: auto;` while on chart itself: `width: 1200px;`